# zoom in zoom out from a point mschart

Tags: c#, mschart, zooming

[image]
How to zoom from a point 
for example zoom from point 300 to 500 axisX and 50 to 100 AxisY step by step

Current location

private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

```
        lastPoint = e.Location;
}
```

Zooming X And Y

```
 private void btnZoomXY_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            step = (int)(chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum - lastPoint.X ) / 20;
        if (zoomx > chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum)
        {
            zoomx -= step;

        }
        else
            zoomx += step;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(lastPoint.X+ zoomx, this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum - zoomx);


        if (Mode == SpectometrMode.Absorbance)
        {
            step1 = 0.2f;
        }
        else
             step1 = (int)(chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum - lastPoint.Y) / 20;
        if (zoomY > chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum)
        {
            zoomY -= step1;

        }
        else
            zoomY += step1;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(lastPoint.Y+ zoomY, this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum - zoomY);




        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0}";
    }
```

@taW

Comment: Hehe, this kind of Ping doesn't work. You need to a) know the current zoom center and your steps. Then the code should work. Always keep the center in the midle between [zoom start and -end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscaleview.zoom?view=netframework-4.7.2). If the center is at x=400 and the current zoom is at xstart= 100 you have a xdelta=300. For step=100 you can zoom to `(origin-i*step, origin+i*step)`

Comment: @TaW my steps is different I have 3 mode in code . current zoom center showing by mouse click.  please help me  write this code .Thanks

Comment: I'll have a look later..

Comment: I found the code a little confusing. My answer adresses the prime issue of wrong coordinates and shows a simple zooming scheme. Adapt as needed..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that will zoom in 2x with each click.

It uses a variable `span` as the range of values that will be visible in the zoomed view.

It also moves the clicked position to the next closest `DataPoint`. You may remove this to allow zooming in on positions between `DataPoints`.

Let's see it in action:

[image]

Note that **the first issue with your code** is the coordinates you use.

These are **three**  (!) coordinate systems in `MSChart`:

- **Pixels** as in `MouseClick`
- **Values** as in `Axis` values
- **Positions** as in `ElementPositions` i.e. **percentages** related to the next higher container

Your main issue is that you **mix pixels with values** which will result in chaos.

You need to **convert** the pixels to values as in the code shown.

Here are the variables I use:

```
double span = 0;                     // axis range in values
Point lastPoint = Point.Empty;       // the clicked position
PointF clickedValues = PointF.Empty; // the values of the clicked positiom
DataPoint closePoint = null;         // the next closest DataPoint
```

Now the click code with the conversion:

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lastPoint = e.Location;
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    if (closePoint != null) closePoint.MarkerColor = chart1.Series[0].MarkerColor;

    clickedValues = new PointF((float)ax.PixelPositionToValue(lastPoint.X),
                               (float)ay.PixelPositionToValue(lastPoint.Y));

    closePoint = chart1.Series[0].Points.Where(x => x.XValue >= clickedValues .X).First();
    closePoint.MarkerColor = Color.Red;  // optionally mark the point

    // optionally move clicked position to actual datapoint
    nextDPoint = new PointF((float)closePoint.XValue, (float)closePoint.YValues[0]);

    span = ax.Maximum - ax.Minimum;  // the full range of values
}
```

Finally the code for the zoom-in button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    span /= 2;  // zoom in 2x each time
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    ax.ScaleView.Zoom(nextDPoint.X - span, nextDPoint.X + span);
}
```

A few notes:

- The conversion functions are only available after the chart has finished layout.
- I only zoom the x-axis and I only zoom-in. Adding y-axis zoom and zooming-out should be simple..
- changing the speed or step size is also not rocket science. Note that the steps should be a **factor** to allow a good user experience. If you **add** (instead of multiply) the zooming will not look linear but will either get faster or slower with each step..
- Of course the markers and the visualization of the clicked points is optional and may not work well with your chart.
- I use a `PointF` to store the clicked values. Usually `floats` will do; this may not be true if the values are `DateTime`, though. In such a case do use two `doubles`!
- Note how I put the `Axis` into **variables**. I usually do the same with `Series` and `ChartAreas`. Much **easier** to write, read and I think even (a little) **faster** to run.. .